# How to let a user have their own chatroom and map marker in firebase?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase

I made an app that can let user log in and set marker on the google map and the marker connect to a chatroom that belongs to the user who set it.

the problem now is I can't get uid in  Chatactivity and MapFragment no matter how i tried,I don't what's the problem
here is the three activity :

can someone please help me~~

LoginActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    //authenticate user
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // there was an error
                        if (password.length() < 6) {
                            edUserid.setError("密碼太短，請輸入超過6個字元!");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "登入失敗", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"登入成功",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });




}
```

ChatActivity:

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

            // Read the input field and push a new instance
            // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference(CHAT_PATH)
                    .push()
                    .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                    .getCurrentUser()
                                    .getDisplayName())
                    );

            // Clear the input
            input.setText("");
        }
    });
    ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
            R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(CHAT_PATH)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

MapFragment(part of it):

```
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


        mFirebaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Map/"+userUID);
        mFirebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                LatLng myLatLon = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class).toLatLng();

                // stash the key in the title, for recall later

                Marker myMarker = mgoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(myLatLon).draggable(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.seedloc2)).title(dataSnapshot.getKey()));

                // cache the marker locally
                markers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), myMarker);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LatLng myLatLon = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseMarker.class).toLatLng();

                // Move markers on the map if changed on Firebase
                Marker changedMarker = markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                changedMarker.setPosition(myLatLon);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Marker deadMarker = markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                deadMarker.remove();
                markers.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                Log.v(TAG, "moved !" + dataSnapshot.getValue());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.v(TAG, "canceled!" + databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());

    mgoogleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean with "combining" and "stored different way"?

Comment: Please include your firebase database and activity in the post.

Comment: Here is my database : http://imgur.com/jZgwKSY
Hello I'd like to store my marker and chat data in the user account section ,but I don't how to do.

Comment: Please do not put links or images to Firebase structures in your question. They are not searchable and if we need to use them in the answer, we have to retype it. You can get your Firebase structure as TEXT from the Firebase Console->Three dots on right->Export JSON. Also, you did not include any info about what a *map marker* is or what that dataset looks like. Can you update your question and we'll take a look. Oh, including that much code is a LOT to look at, can you just include the relevant bits you are having difficulty with?

Comment: I see,this is my first time to ask questions here,thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database structure should be like this :

- Contacts

  - [userId]

    - email
    - password
- Markers

  - [userid]

    - latitude
    - longitude
    - uid

Chat

- [userid]

  - [keyMessage from push]

    - messageText
    - messageTime
    - messageUser

With this structure you can get the chatroom id from marker, And you can display user info from marker too using the `userId`.

And instead of using `userId` from push, It will much better using uid from firebase auth.

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(CreateActivity.this, new 
          OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

            public void onComplete( Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "創建成功，請重新登 入", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this, "認證失敗或帳號已 存在" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                // insert user to database
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    String currentUid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Contacts/" + currentUid);
                    ContactInfo contact1 = new ContactInfo(email,id,password);
                    myRef.setValue(contact1);//將會員資料寫入FIREBASE
                    startActivity(new Intent(CreateActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,I'll try that.

Comment: Hello! When I tried to write  String currentUid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); in my MapFragment,it crashed 
I don't know why?